# Magento 2.2.6 upgradation error?

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.6

[image]

I try to upgrade my site magento2.2.4 to magento2.2.6 but it shows the following error

Answer (score 0):

Try after setting default file and folder permission as below.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: thank you I didn't understand clearly